# Simplify the following: $\sqrt {k^2+4k}-k-2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I simplify the following expression?

$\sqrt {k^2+4k}-k-2$

Comment: Are you sure any simplification exists? The best thing I can think of is a right triangle with sides k+2, 2, and $\sqrt{k^2+4k}.$

Comment: You cannot. It's already simplified as much as it can be

Comment: I don't believe your expression can be simplified. At least nothing *obvious* comes to mind.

Comment: I guess the OP is looking for $$-\left[(k+2)-\sqrt{k^2+4k}\right]=-\frac{4}{(k+2)+\sqrt{k^2+4k}}$$ to check that such a number is negative and has the same magnitude of $-\frac{2}{k}$ for large values of $k$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Thank you!

Comment: Jack's comment makes sense. It is also possible to set $j=k+2$ so that the expression $(k+2)\pm \sqrt {k^2+4k}$ becomes $j\pm \sqrt {j^2-4}$ - and this might make it easier to see what is going on. Of course if $k$ is large, so is $j$.